# Django 1.11: ImportError: cannot import name [view]

Tags: django, import, view, importerror

I'm trying to add ChartsJS as an extra view in my Django App but I keep getting an Import Error. I have no idea why. I don't have any circular dependencies as far as I can find. Similar StackOverflow questions don't seem to match the problem. I'm totally stuck.

The problematic view is **Analytics** view.

project/app/urls.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import (
    absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
)

from django.conf.urls import url
from future import standard_library
from survey.views import ConfirmView, IndexView, SurveyCompleted, SurveyDetail, AnalyticsView
from survey.views.survey_result import serve_result_csv

standard_library.install_aliases()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='survey-list'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/', SurveyDetail.as_view(), name='survey-detail'),
    url(r'^csv/(?P<pk>\d+)/', serve_result_csv, name='survey-result'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/completed/', SurveyCompleted.as_view(),
        name='survey-completed'),
    url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)-(?P<step>\d+)/', SurveyDetail.as_view(),
        name='survey-detail-step'),
    url(r'^confirm/(?P<uuid>\w+)/', ConfirmView.as_view(),
        name='survey-confirmation'),
    url(r'^analytics/$', AnalyticsView.as_view(),
        name='analytics-view'),
]
```

project/app/views/analytics_view.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import (
    absolute_import, division, print_function, unicode_literals
)
from builtins import super
from future import standard_library

from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

standard_library.install_aliases()

import arrow


class AnalyticsView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "survey/analytics.html"
...
```

I've read it may be to do with Settings, but I can't see any configuration problems there -

project/settings.py:

```
ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_URL = '/bootstrap_admin/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.normpath(os.path.join(ROOT, '..', "survey", "static")),
]
```

Traceback:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x05CBB9F0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 254, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\ronaldg\Documents\csa-survey\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    url(r'^survey/', include('survey.urls')),
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls\__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\ronaldg\Documents\csa-survey\survey\urls.py", line 9, in <module>
    from survey.views import ConfirmView, IndexView, SurveyCompleted, SurveyDetail, AnalyticsView
ImportError: cannot import name AnalyticsView
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: did you try use virtualenv and a newest python version?

Comment: I'm using a virtualenv (pipenv). I'm using Python 2.7 but would the version matter? "from app.views import ViewX, ViewY, ViewZ" was working until I added "AnalyticsView". This says to me the Python version isn't the problem, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted shows that your AnalyticsView is in its own file; you need to import that file.

```
from survey.views.analytics_view import AnalyticsView
```

Comment: Could you expand / point me to some docs by any chance? I'm working with this app https://github.com/Pierre-Sassoulas/django-survey - all of the views are their own files, in a folder called Views. It would be good to understand why it was built like that. I simply appended the existing from "app.views import..." with Analytics view, so I struggle a bit to understand why it didn't work. Would be good to get a good understanding. Thanks

Comment: That totally works - it imports now. So any idea why the rest of the views being imported don't follow the same structure when they are also files containing class-based views? Can they be "registered" somewhere else?

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file inside the views directory? It might be importing the classes there, which makes them available directly at `...views`.

Comment: As Daniel suggests, if you look in the [`survey/views/__init__.py`](https://github.com/Pierre-Sassoulas/django-survey/blob/9416d0fc618a63a210a7feb78e742199ace1d98c/survey/views/__init__.py), you can see that `SurveyCompleted` and some other views are imported and listed in `__all__`, therefore you can use `from survey.views import SurveyCompleted` for convenience. However `AnalyticsView` is not imported in the `__init__.py` so you have to import it from its module.

Comment: @Alasdair - I thought an __init__.py file was just there to say "this is a python folder", but I just took a look inside and can see all of the imports in the format that Daniel Roseman suggested - it all makes sense now =) thanks to the both of you, your answers were exceedingly helpful.